# azure webrole Global.Application_Start is never called

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, application-start

I created a simple ASP.NET project and then added cloud deployment descriptor using Visual Studio. Once I do that, Application_Start() method in global.asax file never gets called. In my project, I do lot of initialization such as loading web.config file, loading connection strings, initiailizing cache, etc. I can not put all of them into WebRole.OnStart() method.

Is there any special configuration required to have Application_Start() method in Global class invoked?

Thanks,
Prasanna

Comment: Appears to be cross-posted on MSDN: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/d1942ee0-71af-4dda-9679-17328c887d93

Comment: There's nothing special you have to do. It should just work. How do you know Application_Start isn't being called?

Comment: Yes. I put it into both the forums, hoping to get quick response. I put a debug point in Application_Start and it doesnt stop there, where as it stops at WebRole.OnStart() debug point.

Comment: Strange...Inside the Application_Start() method, I set Application property and to my surprise, that is being called. So it appears to be a bug or feature!! - Application_Start() in Global is not called during the debug. But that method is infact called and initialization does happen. So works fine now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As SMARX stated Applicaton_start() is always called however with your Web Role if you have full IIS role then VS2010 debugger does not hit Application_start(). I am writing the detail below on how you can hit BP at Application_Start() in Global.asax.cs:

First you can write Debugger.Break() code in your Application_Start() as below:
[image]

Now please open your Role Properties > Web and select

1. Use Visual Studio Development Server settings (I have chosen as shown in image below)
2. Use Local IIS Web Server

[image]

Now debug your application and you will see a message as below to debug W3WP.EXE process

[image]

Select Debug option above and then you will see BS JIT Debugger Windows as below:

[image]

Once you accept VS JIT debugger launch process, you will see the PB hit in your Applicaton_start() as below:

[image]

That's it!!

Comment: Thanks. It helps. Although I dont need it now, I hope this instruction helps someone else.